# implementing parallelization using classloader in junit, Not working out for me

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to implement the test execution in parallel , but is not working out for me. 
I added all dependency as below.

```
    </Script>
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>2</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <parallel>methods</parallel>
                <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </Script>
```

The main reason is, I am using a Browser Driver class which is from our in-build jar files, which i can't change. Hence i am not able to do it.

Want an alternate solution like extending our existing Browser class and implementing parallelism. such that it works for our static data & member functions.

If standalone code which is independent of all and works for me. 
Will be very helpful.

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Normally this will not run tests in parallel, it will run JUnit runner classes in parallel and so in order to run parallel you should have multiple junit runner classes and one junit runner class can have any number of test cases coded in it.

Comment: Thanks you so much.

I have a class file which has all the test methods. Also I Got the below code which can implement it. 
[link] (https://github.com/ravikulkarni/parallel_junit) 

But i am getting Error has below

Comment: what is this link

Comment: the link is where the code is for parallel testing, 
i am getting exceptions which is less information , am not able to resolve it. 
JunitParallelRunner: java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
JunitParallelRunner: java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
JunitParallelRunner: java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)